# can I modify a html link in order to be able to access a jquery/ajax function

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple ink using the `</a>` tag. which is below:

`<a href="create_session.php">`

What my question is can I modify the link in order to be able to access a jquery/ajax function which is below:

```
function removesession()
{       
     $.ajax({
         url: "insertmarks.php",
         async: false,
         type: "POST"
     });    
}
```

Btw is the ajax correct to simply just navigate to a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely!

Give the link an 'id' attribute (makes it easier to select)

```
<a href="create_session.php" id="createLink"></a>

$(function() {
    var link = $("#createLink");

    link.click(function() {
        $.ajax({
           url: "insertmarks.php",
           async: false,
           type: "POST",
           success: function() {
                window.location.href = link.attr("href");
           }
         });

         //cancels the links true action of navigation
         return false;
    });
);
```

Comment: Will the above code navigate the user to see the create_session.php page or the insertmarks.php page? I want the user to see the create_session.php page

Comment: Then use Calin's answer, but add success event handler to the Ajax call, in which you will redirect user to create_session.php. In other words, when someone clicks the link, there will be an Ajax request to the insertmarks.php file, and after it's done, you will be taken to the create_session.php

Comment: Ah, no, this will stop - just remove the 'return false'

Comment: @Calvin.Allen But then he will be taken to create_session.php before Ajax request is actually made. He needs to wait for the request to complete first.

Comment: Interesting.  I was under the impression the JS would execute first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Add a unique id to the anchor tag and bind a click to the remove session function.

```
<a id="myLink" href="create_session.php"></a>

$('#myLink').on('click', removesession);
```

Note that if you don't want the link to navigate to the url, you will need to `return false` in the function `removesession`.

> **Btw is the ajax correct to simply just navigate to a page?**

This will just send a request to the url set in the ajax call. If you would like to change the link's location you can do this

```
$('#myLink').attr('href', 'mylink.php');
```

Comment: I think for performance reasons he should use a class and instead of using .on he should use the .click again for performance reasons. Your answer is however __valid__.

Comment: Why class as opposed to ID?

Comment: A class would be less efficient because you can multiple instances in a document.